# How to store selected value in ng-model if source list is array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have array of objects like:

```
vm.items = [{id: "1", val: "a"},{id: "2", val: "b"},{id: "3", val: "c"}]
```

And I bound it to select option like:

```
<select ng-model="vm.model.id" >
    <option value="">select somthing</option>
    <option ng-repeat="i in vm.items" value="{{i.id}}">{{i.val}}</option>
</select>
```

But when I select some item from dropdown I get whole object `{}` and I want only id.
How can I do that?

Comment: is it showing the whole object as the dropdown item, or are you seeing the whole object when logging a change on the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ng-options directly on the select tag. If your json contains an id and name variable you can specify it as this:

```
<select ng-model="vm.model.id" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in vm.items">
    <option value="">select somthing</option>
</select>
```

The i.id is set to the options value and the i.name is set to the text

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-model` and `ng-options` in `select` to achieve this.

Inside controller.js

```
$scope.selectedItem = "";
```

Markup

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem " name="state"
        ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in vm.items">
    <option value="">select somthing</option>
</select>
```